# A category is filtered if and only if every finite diagram has a cocone

Tags: category-theory

Let $ \mathsf I $ be a category. Let's call $ \mathsf I $ *filtered* if

1. $ \mathsf I $ has at least one object;
2. for every $ i,j\in \mathsf I $, there exists $ k\in \mathsf I $ and morphisms $ i\to k $, $ j\to k $;
3. for every $ i,j\in \mathsf I $ and for every pair of parallel morphism $ \sigma,\tau\colon i\rightrightarrows j $, there exists $ k\in \mathsf I $ and a morphism $ \pi \colon j\to k $ such that $ \pi \circ \sigma = \pi\circ \tau $.

I'm trying to show the following.

> Let $ \mathsf I $ be a category. Then $ \mathsf I $ is filtered if and only if every finite diagram in $ \mathsf I $ has a cocone.

Unfortunately, I got stuck in proving that $ \mathsf I $ filtered implies the existence of cocones. Here's what I tried so far.

Let $ \mathsf I $ be filtered, and let $ F\colon \mathsf C\to \mathsf I $ be a functor from a finite category $ \mathsf C $ to $ \mathsf I $. If $ \mathsf C $ has only one object $ X_1 $, then by (2) there is $ i\in \mathsf I $ and an arrow $ \colon FX_1\to i $. We call $ \mu_{X_1} $ this arrow $ \mu_{X_1}\colon Fx_1\to i $. If $ \mathsf C $ has two objects $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $, then again by (2) there are $ i_1,i_2\in \mathsf I $ and arrows $ FX\to i_1 $, $ FY\to i_2 $, and applying (2) another time we obtain $ k\in \mathsf I $ and two arrows $ i_1\to k $, $ i_2\to k $. This time we call $ \mu_{X_1} $ and $ \mu_{X_2} $ the arrows $ \mu_{X_1},\mu_{X_2}\colon FX_1,FX_2\to k $ obtained by composing the arrows $ FX_r\to i_r $ and $ i_r\to k $, for $ r = 1,2 $. By induction, if $ \mathsf C $ has $ n $ elements then there exists $ k\in \mathsf I $ and a family $ \mu = {\left(\mu_{X}\colon FX\to k\right)}_{X\in \mathsf C} $ of morphisms $ \mu_X\colon FX\to k $, one for every $ X\in \mathsf C $. I've not been able to go further, and show that the family $ \mu $ satisfies the cocone condition. How can I prove that for every $ f\colon X\to Y $ in $ \mathsf C $, $ \mu_Y\circ Ff = \mu_X $?

Comment: You don’t. You haven’t used condition (3). Also you should think about where you might have implicitly used condition (1).

Comment: Mm, I think I employed (1) when I said that there is an object $ FX $ in $ \mathsf I $ for $ X\in \mathsf C $. Is it plausible? By the way, I tried to use (3) somewhere, but all I concluded was that given $ f\colon X\to Y $ in $ \mathsf C $, there exist $ k^\prime\in \mathsf I $ and $ \pi\colon k\to k^\prime $ such that $ \sigma\circ \mu_Y\circ Ff = \sigma\circ \mu_X $. But from there?

Comment: OK. So you can improve your candidate so that the cocone diagram commutes for one $f$. Can you do it for two? Three? etc.

Comment: Ok, so using (3) I can prove that diagrams $ \bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet $ have a cocone. By induction, I concluded that every diagram consisting of two points and $ n $ arrows between these two points have a cocone. A this point I could try to show that any finite diagram of the form $ \bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet \rightrightarrows \cdots\rightrightarrows \bullet $ (with $ n_j $ arrows betwen the $ j $th and the $ j + 1 $th point) has a cocone. But I'm not particularly sure I'm not over complicating things.